# How do I make algolia search work with kitsu's anime content api -- using the index/indices and key/s provided by kitsu?

Tags: javascript, search, algolia

I cant seem to figure out how to connect algolia/algoliasearch to kitsu api: https://hummingbird-me.github.io/api-docs/#tag/Algolia

I was able to do the OAuth part. I am now trying to connect it to algolia.

Per kitsu:

> Kitsu uses Algolia for searching. Algolia's search provides more accurate search results and allows you to build complex search filters to find exactly what you want.

And as per the documentation I need to retrieve the keys and indices that I will use to connect to algolia:

> All Algolia Keys - Get all the Algolia Keys needed to search Kitsu with Algolia.

So I was able to do that as well -- I had to fetch it from kitsu:

```
fetch('https://kitsu.io/api/edge/algolia-keys')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
```

[screenshot of the keys / indices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EePWY.png)

I have tried creating an account with algolia. I found tutorials but all of them would just create their own index and import dummy JSON data.

I was able to do this (create a new empty index from scratch):

https://github.com/algolia-samples/api-clients-quickstarts/blob/master/javascript/simple.js

...but it is still not giving any hint or example how to consume or use an external key or index that is not from my own algolia account. I just need to use the index and key that i got from that GET request from kitsu so that i can implement search using algolia on kitsu's anime content on the website im trying to build.

Comment: you dont need to create an algolia account. you are now getting index names and respective search keys. you need to use those and create a connection to the index. one example https://codesandbox.io/s/5y28llyxw4 see line 16-19

Comment: that's what im thinking as well.. but how exactly is what I'm trying to figure out.. if i  can only find an example.. i believe you got that example from the docs and it's actually doing the same thing which is connecting to their own account by providing their own appid, adminkey and connecting to an existing index/collection that they have under that account..

`const searchClient = algoliasearch(
  'B1G2GM9NG0', // app id
  'aadef574be1f9252bb48d4ea09b5cfe5' // admin key
);

<InstantSearch indexName="demo_ecommerce" searchClient={searchClient}>`

Comment: i think the key and index provided by kitsu is a different type of key -- a search-only key... im just not sure how to implement/use or piece this together..

Comment: Yeah it's a search only key. I'm not sure what they let you search on kitsu. But once you connect to index you must be able to get results back after sending a search query

Comment: Btw the codesandbox example provided also has a search only key. Never expose admin keys as they allow adding/delete data from index

Comment: Yup. Everything @cmgchess said. You'll need an AppID and Search Only API Key from Kitsu's API. Then you use those to initialize the search client using the Algolia library similar to the codesandbox above. Once you're connect you can query against any of the indices Kitsu exposes (characters, media, posts, etc). using the Algolia API/SDK.